# In lavaan, how do you allow all manifest indicators to covary?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, latent-variable, lavaan

When building and developing a model with *lavaan*, e.g.,

```
model <- '

  LV =~ manifest1 + manifest2 + manifest3 + manifest4 + manifest5

'

fit <- cfa(model, data = dat)
```

the modification indices suggest I should allow the manifest indicators to covary e.g., I get:

> manifest1 ~~ manifest2

> manifest2 ~~ manifest3

as suggested modification indices. But indeed, all these indicators should be allowed to covary, because they are highly correlated. Do I have to specify all the paths between the possible combinations of covariances manually, or is there a simple way to allow them all to covary?

I thought fixed.x = FALSE might do this, but I still get the same suggested modification indices.

Comment: This looks like an R question.

Comment: It depends. Maybe there is a statistical reason why it doesn't appear easy to achieve what I've asked?

Comment: Indeed `fixed.x=FALSE` should relax variances.  A double check on the environment with `lavOptions` that it is set accordingly might be good. Also there is an option to provide covariance matrix, if that is `NULL`, maybe laavan omits`fixed.x` option.